# Would setting a field in a class as a new instance of the same class cause memory overflow? InetValidator class (apache.commons)

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am using `InetValidator` class from apache.commons in my project to validate IP addresses. While going through the source code,

```
public class InetAddressValidator implements Serializable {
    private static final int IPV4_MAX_OCTET_VALUE = 255;
    private static final int MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT = 65535;
    private static final int BASE_16 = 16;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -919201640201914789L;
    private static final String IPV4_REGEX = "^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$";
    private static final int IPV6_MAX_HEX_GROUPS = 8;
    private static final int IPV6_MAX_HEX_DIGITS_PER_GROUP = 4;
    private static final InetAddressValidator VALIDATOR = new InetAddressValidator();
    private final RegexValidator ipv4Validator = new RegexValidator("^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$");

    public InetAddressValidator() {
    }

    public static InetAddressValidator getInstance() {
        return VALIDATOR;
    }
```

I observed there is a `VALIDATOR` field which is calling the constructor again.
What I'm confused with is if I create a new instance of this class as,

```
InetAddressValidator addressValidator = new InetAddressValidator();
```

won't it will recursively keep creating new instances of the same class (as the field `VALIDATOR` creates a new instance everytime) and eventually I'm gonna run out of heap space?

I haven't tested this yet, but wondering if this is something I have to keep in mind while testing.

Comment: You can observe a clear case of programmer-itis here in the first three declarations: as if anybody is going to change the maximum octet value, or the maximum unsigned `short`, or 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static final InetAddressValidator VALIDATOR = new InetAddressValidator();
```

it's a static field, so it will be instantiated just once at class load time, not per-instance in the constructor.

Comment: Ah my bad, don't know how I overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Recursive call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE2HZ.png)

InetAddressValidator addressValidator = new InetAddressValidator(); Recursive call